# Dual x-axis histogram (top and bottom of plot) showing distributions of temperature for two different cities

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, gridextra

I am trying to create one plot that has 2 x-axes. I want two histograms within this one plot, one on the top for city A (upside down), and one on the bottom for city B. I want the x-axes to show temperature in degrees.

I have tried several different ways to get started, but all of them have failed. I am very limited and am mostly modifying copied code from the internet.

```
city<-c(A, B, A, B, A, B)
temp<-c(20, 25, 30, 35, 30, 40)
data<-data.frame(city, temp)

g.top <- ggplot(data, aes(x = temp)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,-30,6),units="points"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust =0.25)) +
  geom_histogram()
g.bottom <- ggplot(data, aes(x = temp)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,5,1,1),units="points")) +
  geom_histogram()
grid.arrange(g.top,g.bottom, heights = c(1/5, 4/5))


p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = temp, y=city)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=variable))
```

When I run the first block of code it gives me two separate histograms stacked and says:

> ```
> stat_bin() using bins = 30. Pick better value with binwidth.
> ```

but it doesn't give me a second x axis in any case.

The second code gives me an error saying that I cant use statbin with a y aesthetic, which makes sense to me, but I'm out of ideas at this point.

I am really discouraged, and would really, really appreciate any advice

Comment: `cowplot::plot_grid(g.top, g.bottom, nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(1, 4), align = 'hv')` ? I can't tell what you are trying to do for the second one, since there is no `variable` in your data.

Comment: Perhaps you simply want `ggplot(data, aes(temp)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(city~., scales = 'free')`? Why do you need two _x_ axes, but are plotting two panels _above_ each other?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the margin of the top plot to `-30`? This tends to remove the x-axis of the top plot.

Comment: I am woefully inadequate when it comes to R. I am trying to have two histograms on one plot, but the closest I could get was trying to make two panels. I'm trying to make one panel, two x-axes, one y axis, one histogram hanging from the top axis like a stalactite, and the other histogram like regular from the bottom x axis. I'm completely at a loss of how to do this. My boss wants me to do this, and she may as well have asked me to build a rocket ship.

Comment: Maybe you can find an example of this somewhere—I can't quite picture it. What I'm imagining doesn't seem like a great way to display data, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot histograms separately, one for each city:

1. Top with y-axis flipped, and x-axis labels at the top.
2. Bottom one plot as usual
3. Set x-axis limits the same for **both** plots, so that when we align x-axis vertically using *cowplot:plotgrid* x-axis will align.

See example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

#bigger example data
set.seed(1); data <- data.frame(city = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
                                temp = sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE))

g.top <- ggplot(data[ data$city == "A", ], aes(x = temp)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 50), position = "top") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_minimal() 

g.bottom <- ggplot(data[ data$city == "B", ], aes(x = temp)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 50)) +
  theme_minimal()


plot_grid(g.top, g.bottom, 
          labels = c("City A", "City B"), nrow = 2, align = 'hv')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much; this is awesome! It would've taken me millions of years to do what you just did.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily the easiest way to get there, but gives control along the way. I'm approaching this as a data reshaping exercise. First I get the count of each temperature for each city, then figure out how much space there is between those counts, and then plot a normal stacked `geom_col`.

```
# Get the counts
library(tidyverse)
my_data_transform <- data %>%
  count(temp, city, name = "count")

# Take that, and append after it rows that measure the "space between" each city's counts at each temperature.
my_data_transform2 <- bind_rows(
  my_data_transform,
  my_data_transform %>% 
    count(temp, wt = count, name = "count") %>%
    mutate(city = " ",
           count = 15 - count)  # Adjust to taste
  ) %>%
  # For plotting, I want the "space between" rows to be plotted in between the two cities.
  #  This is accomplished by making the city an ordered factor and putting the blanks 2nd.
  mutate(city = city %>% fct_relevel(" ", after = 1))

# Plot as geom_col, specifying clear bars for the middle ones.
ggplot(my_data_transform2, aes(temp, count, fill = city)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", NA, "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, name = "") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing! Thank you so much. The only problem is that when I try to run the second block of code (after getting the counts but before the plot) I get the error "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (closure) of argument." I thought maybe it was because temp should be numeric, so I used as.numeric for temp, but now I get: "Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" Thank you so much Jon Spring. I'm so close, but I don't know why I can't get your code to run.

Comment: What data are you using, and what data types are your variables? Can you give more information about what you're feeding into it so I could replicate your problem?

Comment: Hey Jon Spring, is there any way you could private message or email me? I could just send you my csv file. I really want to make your code work, but still can't figure it out a week later. My email is dickeyg51388@gmail.com